# Google Sheets - copy to another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a workbook that I need to use to upload files automatically to a point, basically, it resolves around taking a sku from master sheet A2 and then copying it exactly six times on a different sheet before moving to A3 and copying that SKU 6 times.

Right now I am using an array formula to just autofill, so I would want it something like that, but just copy 6 times for each filled cell. I used the following for different sheets to autofill.

```
=ArrayFormula(Magento!A2:A)
```

Array formula wouldn't work for my image tab, Here is a copy of the sheet I already populated by hand, but basically it is from the first sheet tab, Magento and going to the Image_Extras sheet. Each Sku needs 6 rows for 6 image positions.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/107Va2LStSyz3My7Jcb9di4DsZtt_am40_grg0q_wIXQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between your question and your shared Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you about the detail of your goal using the sample input and output values? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see [how-do-i-ask-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After doing so please edit you question and title. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(REPT(
 IF(Magento!A2:A="",,"×"&Magento!A2:A), 6),,9^9), "×"))))
```

[image]